# Getting room bookings on the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs

I want to develop a room booking scheduler with a timeline view similar to [Scheduler](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml)

I can't figure out how to attach the room bookings from the Bookings table in the database onto the grid/the table (Seen in the link). Also how to change the bookings as and when the date is changed to previous or next months in the appropriate time sections and rooms.

I'm open to using any JavaScript framework to develop it. Kindly advise!

Answer (score 0):

Every Framework got an API Documentation otherwise its simply not good. Take a look at [addEvent()](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_addevent.html) or more common [Scheduler API Reference](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__refs__scheduler.html). Another good UI Framework is [Kendo UI](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui).

```
scheduler.addEvent({

    start_date: "16-06-2013 09:00",
    end_date:   "16-06-2013 12:00",
    text:   "Meeting",
    holder: "John", //userdata
    room:   "5"     //userdata

});
```